# Debugging LPC812 Cortex m0 MCUs

Tags: lpc, swd

Is this possible to debug applications on this MCU? Does anyone have experience with this? As datasheet says it is possible to debug in SWD mode but with JLINK /Keil & LPCLINK/LPCEXPRESSO we had no success.

Schematic is a simple breakout board. I soldered SWD pins to MCU's pins. I connected :Pin5:SWCLK/Pin6:SWDIO/Pin3:Reset and GND to LPC812 & JLINK.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your schematics? SWD should be available.

Comment: Schematic is a simple breakout board,i soldered SWD pins to MCU's pins. I connected :Pin5:SWCLK/Pin6:SWDIO/Pin3:Reset and GND to LPC812 & JLINK.